# How to cluster markers to show on Google Map, iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps, coordinates, markerclusterer

I log every coordinate received from location manager in iOS. I draw custom shapes on another layer (`UIView`) and I do not add markers to Google Map View object. I use projection to draw shapes. When number of the coordinates are increased in quantity, I should not try to draw every single one in a loop, because of the performance.

So, I am trying to find a way to filter out coordinates and not even check things in a loop to see if it is in the current bounds of the map view or the screen..

Is there an algorithm or a known technic to do this kind of clustering?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Bright parts are composed of **many** "clear color" circles.
Red rectangle represents the visible portion of Google Map View. When drawing the circles in the area marked "B", I also draw the circles in "A". I am trying to find a good way to cluster these at the very first time of saving those points. (So I don't want to loop through all of the points (A+B) and check if rectangle B includes the point at that index of the loop; because it won't make serious improvement. Points in Z for example may be at a very far away position and I must not loop through millions of coordinates. If I am trying to draw points for San Francisco, I must not even have points for Japan, Tokyo in the loop...

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is the wrong term.

You want to simplify curves, I guess, see e.g.

[How to simplify cubic bezier curve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571434/how-to-simplify-cubic-bezier-curve)

Comment: Thank you @Anony-Mousse. This is useful but not exactly what I need. I updated my question.

Comment: Sounds more as if you want on one hand to use indexes such as the R*-tree to avoid those very-far-away points, and on the other hand merge near-identical points (again, something that can be accelerated well with R*-trees).